# referencing static data member

Tags: c++, reference, static

I was reading about **binding a reference to a static data member, or taking its address, if (and only if) it has an out-of-class definition**
(https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#in-class-constant).

And when I tried to test the example (see below) I noticed that it works on Visual Studio 2017 (no error as expected).

I tried with online compilers and I got only one error (not two as expected).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AE {  
public:
    static const int c6 = 7;
    static const int c7 = 31;
};

const int AE::c7; // definition
void byref(const int& a);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    byref(AE::c6); // error: c6 not an lvalue
    byref(AE::c7); // ok
    const int* p1 = &AE::c6; // error: c6 not an lvalue
    const int* p2 = &AE::c7; // ok

    std::cout << "p1 " << *p1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "p2 " << *p2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}

void byref(const int & a)
{
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

Ignoring the Microsoft compiler for the moment...

When compiling this program I got `undefined reference to AE::c6` which with a little trick found on stack changing to `byref(+AE::c6);` will resolve it.

But for the other line `const int* p1 = &AE::c6;` as shown by comment said it will generate an error which is not the case (it compiles and runs OK).

So I have 2 questions :

1. What is the unary + role's here?
2. Why the compiler ignored the error `const int* p1 = &AE::c6;`, which is not as I expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, adding the `+` in front of the constant name changes the value from a constant to an expression.  The result of the expression is stored into an unnamed temporary variable, and a reference to this temporary is passed to `byref`.  Without the `+`, a reference is made directly to the constant, which requires the constant to have a definition somewhere in the program.

For the second question, the compiler won't issue a diagnostic during compilation, because the one definition for `AE::c6` could be present in a different source file.  The linker would provide an error when it doesn't find the definition.

The language standard in [class.static.data] says "There shall be exactly one definition of a static data member that is odr-used (6.2) in a program; no
diagnostic is required."  So not having a definition, or having more than one, is a violation but one that is not required to be reported.  In the former case, the compiler/linker may create a definition to use, while in the latter the linker will just pick one of the available definitions.